# How Colors are filled in a bit i.e either 1 or 0?

Tags: display, colors

This question is just out of curiosity and I tried searching for it. But most of the site speak about binary representation and 256 combinations in 8-bit.. This I already know.. I do know that RGB has (255, 255, 255) combinations.. But just consider R with 255 combinations from black to white, How does the computer generate a red color just out of electricity.. Or is it the color filled in the tubes of the screen or monitor used for displaying? Also if RGB takes (255, 255, 255) combinations, then does that mean RGB takes 3 bytes of color combination.. Thanks in advance for solving the query?

Comment: In general, it depends what library one uses to load the image (for example, the default SDL surface format is 32-bit `ARGB` (zero-padded without an alpha channel), whereas OpenCV uses a packed 24-bit format `RGB`, which makes 32-bit aligned access difficult without a prepass of the pixel data).

Comment: @Tog I've already marked the correct answer what I wanted. The person who has given the answer has already understood what I asked for. Then how can the question be unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally to the computer each pixel is stored as a triplet of RGB, each with a value (typically 0 to 255).  These are 8 bit values, which means that they are each represented by a combination of eight 1s and 0s (as you already know).  Because there are 3 colours, and each is represented by 8 bits, that results in a total of 24-bits of colour (hence 24-bit images), or 3 bytes per pixel.

As the computer displays the image to the screen it scans through the display area one pixel at a time, and, depending on the display technology used, sends that information to the screen to be displayed.

For digital display systems (DVI, HDMI, etc) that binary data is sent to the screen for interpretation.  For analogue systems (VGA) the interpretation is done by the computer itself and the results sent to the display.

The interpretation is basically converting each of the 3 bytes into a voltage.  This is done by a device called a DAC, or Digital to Analogue Convertor.  It takes the binary value which represents 0 to 255 and outputs a discrete voltage for each different value.  So, for instance, a binary value of 0 could output a voltage of 0V.  A binary value of 255 could output a voltage of 5V.  A binary value of 93 would therefore output a voltage of 1.823529412V.

There are usually three DAC modules, one for each colour, and the resultant voltages are used by the display to control the brightness of that specific pixel.  In an old CRT it is used to set the intensity of the electron beam.  In a TFT it is used to set the opacity of a subpixel (of which there are usually 3 - one red, one green and one blue).

It is common for TFT screens to not be able to display the full 0-255 colour range in 8 bit detail, so often you get less actual colours displayed.  256K colours, or 18 bit, are common on TFTs, whereas CRTs are capable of displaying the full 24-bit range.  It is also possible to get (if you pay tens of thousands of dollars) "HDRI" monitors (High Dynamic Range Imagery) which are capable of displaying more than the normal 18- or 24-bit colour detail, but these are very rare and only used for specific high-end jobs.

Comment: Heh, thanks. It helps that I have built a VGA card from scratch using a microcontroller ;)

Comment: @Majenko Fabulous.. Exactly what i was looking for.